# Django update form according to another field form

Tags: django, forms, field

I have the following Django form :

```
label = forms.CharField(label="Label",
                        min_length=2,
                        max_length=100,
                        required=True,
                        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control input-sm'}))

hour = forms.ChoiceField(label="Hour",
                         choices=choice_hour,
                         required=True,
                         widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control input-sm'}))

minute = forms.ChoiceField(label="Minute",
                           choices=choice_minute,
                           required=True,
                           widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control input-sm'}))

period = forms.MultipleChoiceField(label="Day of week",
                                   choices=choice_period,
                                   required=True,
                                   error_messages={'required': 'At least you must select one day'},
                                widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(renderer=HorizontalCheckboxRenderer))


snooze = forms.ChoiceField(label="Auto stop",
                           choices=choice_snooze,
                           required=True,
                           widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control input-sm'}))


mode = forms.ChoiceField(label="Mode",
                          choices=choice_mode,
                          required=True,
                          widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control input-sm'}))

if mode == 'music':
        webradio = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Webradio.objects.all(),
                                      widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control input-sm'}), required=False)
    else:
        webradio = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Webradio.objects.all(),
                                  widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control input-sm'}), required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Alarmclock
        fields = ['label', 'hour', 'minute', 'period', 'snooze', 'mode', 'webradio']
```

The 'Mode' field form permit to know if user want 'Radio' or 'Music'.

When the Mode is 'music', webradio field can be empty. 
But when the Mode is 'radio' , webradio field must be set.

How I can update the webradio field form according to the mode ?

I tried with a IF condition, but I think the mode variable is not found, the webradio field is all the time required.

Thanks.

Comment: You'll have to override the `__init__` method to do that. Is this your full form class?

Comment: No, I have some vars/lists/tuples which are initialized at the top of the class (choices_mode, etc...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define webradio field as not required and then do the validation in the clean method (purpose of clean is to do validation of fields that rely on each other).

```
class Form(forms.ModelForm):

    # other fields ...

    mode = forms.ChoiceField(
        label="Mode", choices=choice_mode, required=True,
        widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control input-sm'})
    )
    webradio = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Webradio.objects.all(),
        widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control input-sm'}),
        required=False
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Alarmclock
        fields = ['label', 'hour', 'minute', 'period', 'snooze', 'mode', 'webradio']

    def clean(self):
        mode = self.cleaned_data.get('mode')
        if mode == 'music':
            webradio = self.cleaned_data.get('webradio')
            if not webradio:
                raise forms.ValidationError({'webradio': 'Webradio field is required.'})
```

Check out [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other) for more details.

Note that this method has changed in Django 1.7:

> In previous versions of Django, form.clean() was required to return a dictionary of cleaned_data. This method may still return a dictionary of data to be used, but it’s no longer required.

Comment: Thank you, maybe it's better.  But I have another error, I think it's because my views launch 'form.is_valid()'  after the cleaned_data in this form..

Comment: In my views.py, I have a form.is_valid() on this form.  I've read in the docs that "is_valid()" will pass many "clean_***" methods, and I'm asking if it's not a problem to launch cleaned_data before another..   Sorry, maybe it's not very clear

Comment: It's not a problem, the data is already validated. The clean_* methods work like extra validation. If you want to learn more about the validation process, [check out the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/validation/#form-and-field-validation).

Comment: If the answer did solve your problem, please accept it.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know why, now it works, thank you !  Just I use "forms.ModelForm" which use an automatic ValidationError message, so the custom message don't work.  But I will read more about that.

Comment: Solved.  I replaced   `raise forms.ValidationError('Webradio field is required.')`  by  `raise forms.ValidationError({'webradio': ["Field required for Radio Mode",]})`

Answer (score 0):

I guess this should do the trick.

```
class FormName(forms.ModelForm):

    label = forms.CharField(label="Label",
                            min_length=2,
                            max_length=100,
                            required=True,
                            widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control input-sm'}))

    hour = forms.ChoiceField(label="Hour",
                             choices=choice_hour,
                             required=True,
                             widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control input-sm'}))

    minute = forms.ChoiceField(label="Minute",
                               choices=choice_minute,
                               required=True,
                               widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control input-sm'}))

    period = forms.MultipleChoiceField(label="Day of week",
                                       choices=choice_period,
                                       required=True,
                                       error_messages={'required': 'At least you must select one day'},
                                    widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(renderer=HorizontalCheckboxRenderer))


    snooze = forms.ChoiceField(label="Auto stop",
                               choices=choice_snooze,
                               required=True,
                               widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control input-sm'}))


    mode = forms.ChoiceField(label="Mode",
                              choices=choice_mode,
                              required=True,
                              widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control input-sm'}))

    webradio = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Webradio.objects.all(),
                                      widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control input-sm'}), required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Alarmclock
        fields = ['label', 'hour', 'minute', 'period', 'snooze', 'mode', 'webradio']

    def clean_mode(self):
        mode = self.cleaned_data.get('mode')
        if mode == 'music':
            self.fields['webradio'].required = False
        return super(FormName,self).clean_mode()
```

What it does basically is change the required attribute of the webradio field on the go, depending upon the value of mode.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't works.  'super object has no attribute clean_mode'.  If I delete this line (return), django starts but the form return errors for mode and webradios widgets.

Comment: The mode widget doesn't display any errors, it was my mistake.  But still the webradio widget is in error in each case..   I think I understand the 'super' keyword : it calls the class itself, isn't it ?    It's not a problem to keep all fields values  ?

Comment: super calls the method of the parent class. What exactly is the error? In place of 'FormName' you have to place the name you have assigned to your form class.

Comment: Sorry for my poor explanation, The exact error is that the Webradio-Widget says 'Mandatory Field' on the webpage even if I choose music.  So, webradio field form don't change required to False..

Comment: Ok, after reading the doc, I understand why.  With your code, the page returns `super object has no attribute clean_mode` when the form is sent.  So, I renamed `clean_mode` to `cleanmode` and I think now it doesn't detect the function..   And yes, my FormName is correct.